# Change an int type into char type in C#

Tags: c#, char, integer, calculator, data-conversion

I am trying to break very large numbers digit by digit and add them one by one (for a large numbers calculator).

The conditions are I should not be using any Math or BigNumbers libraries and the inputs must be taken in Strings.

The way I'm doing it is by taking the strings, putting each one into a List of `(char)`, and converting each `(char) to (int)` and do the operations then change the resulting digit back to `(char)` and then add it to a list I named Result.

**I want to know how I should change (int) to (char)? "Convert.ToChar()" does not work as it converts the number to its Unicode character**.
Here's the code and I marked the problems:

```
bool carry = false;
        int i = bigNumberLength - 1;
        List<char> result = new List<char>();
        char currentDigit;
        for (int j = smallNumberLength - 1; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            int tempDigit1 = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(bigNumber[i]);
            int tempDigit2 = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(smallNumber[j]);
            if (tempDigit1 + tempDigit2 < 10)
            {
                if (!carry)
                {
                    currentDigit = Convert.ToChar(tempDigit1 + tempDigit2);//this one
                    carry = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (tempDigit1 + tempDigit2 + 1 < 10)
                        currentDigit = Convert.ToChar(tempDigit1 + tempDigit2 + 1);//this one
                    else
                        currentDigit = Convert.ToChar(0); //this one
                }
                result.Add(currentDigit);
            }
            else
            {
                currentDigit = Convert.ToChar((tempDigit1 + tempDigit2) - 10); //this one
                carry = true;
                result.Add(currentDigit);
            }
            i--;
        }
```

Comment: Please provide your current code and where **exactly** you have problems with it.

Comment: I assume you are looking to use `int.Parse`?

Comment: '0' = 48 and so on, also '2' - '0' = 2 as integer value

Comment: @DavidG By no libraries I'm inclined to understand that this should be solved without `int.Parse` or similar.

Comment: You lost me when you started talking about converting back to char. The proble you are trying to solve is, given a string representation of a number, add up all the digits. Why would you want to convert anything back to `char`, the answer you must provide is a sum.

Comment: @InBetween By libraries, I assume they're not allowed to use things like `BigInteger`, not things in the BCL

Comment: @InBetween I need to turn it back to char in order to add them to the Result List. I'm adding it to a List as large numbers can't be contained in an (int) type.

Comment: If the numbers are too large for int then why not use `long` instead? No need for chars. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types

Comment: @ADyson This should only be done using 'string' and 'long' data type is not allowed. I would love to use 'long' myself if I could, believe me.

Comment: @ADyson It's a homework.

Comment: One way I have thought of is writing a method with an (int) argument, and what it does is it gets the resulting digit, and returns the digit's ASCII value using if statements (there's only 10 digits we need anyways) so when you convert it to char, the number will appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an example I have done the addition and used just string but you could replace it with the logic for list and do the other math on the same way with some changes:

```
    private const char O = '0';

    public static void Main()
    {
        var num1 = "55555555555555555555555555555555555555578955555555555555";
        var num2 = "55555555555555555555555555";
        var result = string.Empty;
        var num1Index = num1.Length - 1;
        var num2Index = num2.Length - 1;
        var temp = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            if (num1Index >= 0 && num2Index >= 0)
            {
                var sum = ((temp + num1[num1Index--] - O) + (num2[num2Index--] - O));
                result = sum % 10 + result;
                temp = sum / 10;
            }
            else if (num1Index < 0 && num2Index >= 0)
            {
                result = temp + (num2[num2Index--] - O) + result;
                temp = 0;
            }
            else if (num1Index >= 0 && num2Index < 0)
            {
                result = temp + (num1[num1Index--] - O) + result;
                temp = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
```

the first if statement do the actual math the rest just appends the rest of the numbers case they are with different length.

and the outpud produced by the script:
[image]

and int to char again you can convert by adding for example

```
(char)([some digit hier] + '0')
```

Comment: Wow! This works perfectly fine and it is way better and cleaner than what I had in mind. I need to read your algorithm a bit more to understand what you did exactly. Thank you so much! I can't mark it as the answer to the question as it may confuse others in future  who want to know how to do direct (int) to (char), but it sure is the better way to do the task at hand.

Comment: Oh I just noticed your edit, you answered the question itself as well. Marking it now!